# Custom FontAwesome icon doesn't render

Tags: angular, svg, angular-fontawesome

**UPDATE :**

[Here is the StackBlitz as requested.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-eqixho)

I created an SVG icon based on FontAwesome's collaborator's [instructions here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/109#issuecomment-502013878), but that doesn't seem to render in HTML. Though it shows the exact element tree as FontAwesome's own icons.

So I created an Icon like following in `tiktok.ts` in the `assets/icons/`

```
import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

export const faTiktok: IconDefinition = {
    prefix: 'fab',
    iconName: 'tiktok',
    icon: [
        512,
        512,
        [],
        'U+E002',
        'M12.53.02C13.84 0 15.14.01 16.44 0c.08 1.53.63 3.09 1.75 4.17 1.12 1.11 2.7 1.62 4.24 1.79v4.03c-1.44-.05-2.89-.35-4.2-.97-.57-.26-1.1-.59-1.62-.93-.01 2.92.01 5.84-.02 8.75-.08 1.4-.54 2.79-1.35 3.94-1.31 1.92-3.58 3.17-5.91 3.21-1.43.08-2.86-.31-4.08-1.03-2.02-1.19-3.44-3.37-3.65-5.71-.02-.5-.03-1-.01-1.49.18-1.9 1.12-3.72 2.58-4.96 1.66-1.44 3.98-2.13 6.15-1.72.02 1.48-.04 2.96-.04 4.44-.99-.32-2.15-.23-3.02.37-.63.41-1.11 1.04-1.36 1.75-.21.51-.15 1.07-.14 1.61.24 1.64 1.82 3.02 3.5 2.87 1.12-.01 2.19-.66 2.77-1.61.19-.33.4-.67.41-1.06.1-1.79.06-3.57.07-5.36.01-4.03-.01-8.05.02-12.07z'
    ],
} as any
```

and imported in `component.ts` like

`import { faTiktok } from 'assets/icons/tiktok';`

assigned it variable in component.ts

and used in the HTML as

`<fa-icon [icon]="faTiktok" matSuffix size='2x'></fa-icon>`

All this shows the same element tree as other FontAwesome icons but doesn't render on page.

I tested the path online and that renders the icon correctly.

Any idea what I could have missed?

Comment: why are you using fab as your prefix? Use something that doesn't conflict with their styles. try using fac maybe or anything else. (So avoid fab, fal, fas, far, fa).

Comment: @WahabShah tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share stackblitz code for viewing. Maybe we can help that way much better.

Comment: @WahabShah buddy, I added the stackblitz link on top. Sorry for the delayed response. I got stuck in something else.

Comment: sure no issues i will check in a bit. Have you put in your this above tiktok code in that aswell?

Comment: Yes the same code

Comment: I can not see your tiktok.ts file anywhere there or the above specific custom code i mean to be specific? I have opened the above link you shared.

Comment: @WahabShah Please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have specified dimension of your SVG view box incorrectly. Your icon is rendered, it is just of a sub-pixel size and therefore you can't see it.

To fix the problem set correct view box dimensions in the icon definition (looks like it is 24x24 for this particular icon):

```
export const faTiktok: IconDefinition = {
    prefix: 'fab',
    iconName: 'tiktok',
    icon: [
        24,
        24,
        [],
        'U+E002',
        'M12.53.02C13.84 0 15.14.01 16.44 0c.08 1.53.63 3.09 1.75 4.17 1.12 1.11 2.7 1.62 4.24 1.79v4.03c-1.44-.05-2.89-.35-4.2-.97-.57-.26-1.1-.59-1.62-.93-.01 2.92.01 5.84-.02 8.75-.08 1.4-.54 2.79-1.35 3.94-1.31 1.92-3.58 3.17-5.91 3.21-1.43.08-2.86-.31-4.08-1.03-2.02-1.19-3.44-3.37-3.65-5.71-.02-.5-.03-1-.01-1.49.18-1.9 1.12-3.72 2.58-4.96 1.66-1.44 3.98-2.13 6.15-1.72.02 1.48-.04 2.96-.04 4.44-.99-.32-2.15-.23-3.02.37-.63.41-1.11 1.04-1.36 1.75-.21.51-.15 1.07-.14 1.61.24 1.64 1.82 3.02 3.5 2.87 1.12-.01 2.19-.66 2.77-1.61.19-.33.4-.67.41-1.06.1-1.79.06-3.57.07-5.36.01-4.03-.01-8.05.02-12.07z'
    ],
} as any
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-eh61ge?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftiktok.ts) for working example.

Comment: Thank you, Yaroslav.  What do you mean by sub-pixel size?

Comment: The whole icon is smaller than a single pixel. Imagine an SVG viewbox of 512x512 points, then icon is only taking 24x24 of that ~4.5% of the size. Now when you try to render icon 16px x 16px you need to scale the 512 points of the viewbox to fit into this 16px square. Now the actual size of the icon square is taking ~4.5% of 16px, which is ~0.7px and actual icon is even smaller, so smaller then 1px on your screen and browser just rounds it to nothing.